# Navigation bar blink

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationbar, caanimation

I'm trying to make my navigation bar to have a blink animation, to show that something is going on in the background. The problem is that the color is too light, I gave a solid color to the animation but on the device it shows just some soft change in color almost unnoticed.

Here is the code:

```
CABasicAnimation *anAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"backgroundColor"];
anAnimation.duration = 3.00;
anAnimation.repeatCount = HUGE_VAL;
anAnimation.autoreverses = YES;
anAnimation.fromValue = (id)[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
anAnimation.toValue = (id)[[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer addAnimation:anAnimation forKey:@"backgroundColor"];
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You could just overlay a `UIView` and animate the UIView from clear to blue. Much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a sublayer of the navigation bar's layer and add the animation in it. Some custom drawing may be breaking your animation if it is added to the "main" layer.
Take note that the color of navigation bars is set using barTintColor property which may differ from backgroundColor of the view/layer under the hood.

Comment: is the navigation bar white?

Comment: Yes, when I set translucident to no, the current layer animation disappears :)

Comment: The navigation bar comes from a navigation controller, I didn't insert the bar manually